# PHP: Separate values in foreach according to key

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, foreach

I am using PHP Laravel.

I need to get the total time/hours of each employee. Each employee has an assigned timeKeeping_empID.
the Time_Logs table has the time logs of the Employees with timeKeeping_empID as the foreign key.

I tried running my code:
Controller:

```
function getTotalHours(Request $request)
        {

            $team = Employees::where('managerID', $request->session()->get('employeeID'))->get();
                //I am assigning an array to be grouped according to my employeeID session.
                $teamIDs = array();
                //I am getting my own session so I can see my data as well together with my team
                array_push($teamIDs, $request->session()->get('employeeID'));
                foreach($team as $member) {
                    array_push($teamIDs, $member->employeeID);
                }
                //I am getting the column employeeID which is the same with the teamID
                $empData = Employees::whereIn('employeeID', $teamIDs)->get();
                $timeKeepingIDs = array();
                foreach($empData as $anEmpData) {
                    array_push($timeKeepingIDs, $anEmpData->timeKeeping_empID);
                }
                $timeLogData = Time_Logs::whereIn('timeKeeping_empID', $timeKeepingIDs)->get();

            return view('welcome', compact('timeLogData','request'));
        }
```

in my view:
$totalHours=0;

```
        foreach ($timeLogData as $timeLogDatas) {

        $dateToday = new DateTime($timeLogDatas->date);
        $timeFrom = date_create($timeLogDatas->time_in);
        $timeTo = date_create($timeLogDatas->time_out);
        $hoursRendered = date_diff($timeFrom, $timeTo);

        $totalHours=$totalHours += (int) $hoursRendered->format('%h');
        }
        echo "$totalHours";
```

but what comes out is the Total Hours of ALL the Employee.
What I need is the total hours of Each employee.

Here is my database table:

```
(Employee) 
EmployeeID (primaryKey) 
timeKeeping_empID 
name


(Time_Logs)
id(primaryKey)
timeKeeping_empID
date
time-in
time-out
```

Sorry, I'm a newbie in PHP.

Comment: It would help if you included a description of your database table

Comment: Also, when you're looping with every employee, you should return back the total hours to zero .

Comment: updated. with database table.

Comment: You can use aggregate function SUM('YOUR-TIME-COL') with GROUP BY timeKeeping_empID in your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a matter of principle of the MVC pattern, you should never put application logic in a View; put all your computation logics in the Controller, and just output the computed values in your view.

Having said that, the reason why you're getting the time data of all employees is because you passed an entire array of employee ID numbers to your Where clause for the timelogdata:

`$timeLogData = Time_Logs::whereIn('timeKeeping_empID',`***$timeKeepingIDs***`)->get();`

By passing an array of employee numbers, you're essentially getting the combined time logs of all the employees within your $timeKeepingIDs array.

There are many ways to go about this, but the simplest might be to create an associative array for all total hours, per employee. You will have to loop through each employee in your $empData array, perform the computation, and save a separate $timesheets array like:

```
//I am getting the column employeeID which is the same with the teamID
$empData = Employees::whereIn('employeeID', $teamIDs)->get();

$timesheets = array();
foreach($empData as $anEmpData) {
    $timeLogData = Time_Logs::whereIn('timeKeeping_empID', $anEmpData->timeKeeping_empID)->get();

    $totalHours = 0;

    $timeLogs = array();
    foreach($timeLogData as &$t) {
        $timeData['dateToday'] = new DateTime($t->date);
        $timeData['timeFrom'] = date_create($t->time_in);
        $timeData['timeTo'] = date_create($t->time_out);
        $timeData['hoursRendered'] = date_diff($timeFrom, $timeTo);
        array_push($timeLogs, $timeData);

        $totalHours=$totalHours += (int) $hoursRendered->format('%h');
    }

    $timesheets[$anEmpData->timeKeeping_empID] = [ 'timeLogs' => $timeLogs, 'totalHours' => $totalHours ];
}

return view('welcome', compact('timesheets','request'));
```

Now, on your view, you may use the `@foreach` Blade directive:

```
<?php
@foreach ($timesheets as $empid => $timesheet)
<p>Timesheet for employee id $empid</p>

    @foreach ($timesheet['timeLogs'] as $timeLog)
        <ul>
        @foreach ($timeLog as $logEntry)

            <li>Date: $logEntry['dateToday']</li>
            <li>Time In: $logEntry['timeFrom']</li>
            <li>Time Out: $logEntry['timeTo']</li>
            <li>Hours rendered: $logEntry['hoursRendered']</li>

        @endforeach
        </ul>
    @endforeach

    Total hours rendered is: $timesheet['totalHours']
@endforeach
?>
```

I haven't tested this on my PC, but I hope you get the idea.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should do is an array of hours instead of summing all of them together :

```
    foreach ($timeLogData as $timeLogDatas) {

    $dateToday = new DateTime($timeLogDatas->date);
    $timeFrom = date_create($timeLogDatas->time_in);
    $timeTo = date_create($timeLogDatas->time_out);
    $hoursRendered = date_diff($timeFrom, $timeTo);

    $totalHours[$timeLogDatas->timeKeeping_empID] = $totalHours[$timeLogDatas->timeKeeping_empID] + (int) $hoursRendered->format('%h');
    }
    print_r("$totalHours");
```

And then you will have an array containing the total of hours by employee.
Then you will have an output like :

```
Array
(
    [123] => 120
    [124] => 95
    [129] => 195
)
```

Where the key is the employee Id, and the value, his total of hours.

Comment: It says "Cannot use a scalar value as an array"

Comment: Did you try to declare variable as array like `$totalHours=array();`

Comment: yes. I tried changing the $totalHours=0; to $totalHours=array(); but another error occur and says "Undefine Offset: 5" . And I think this is something to do with the array.

Comment: At which line did you get the error ?
Did you do additionnal treatment of this array after the code we can see ?

Comment: Maybe you are using a foreach on the employees, and when you do the `$totalHours[$anEmpData->EmployeeID]` on the fifth employee (employee with id = 5), there is no match in the time_logs table.
If you are doing somthing similar to this, add a `if (!empty($totalHours[$anEmpData->EmployeeID]))` before to make sure he is set in the array

Answer (score 0):

Hey i will show you Laravel magic :P

```
function getTotalHours(Request $request)
{
$timeLogData = Time_Logs::groupBy('timeKeeping_empID')->selectRaw('sum(time_out-time_in) as workingHours, timeKeeping_empID')->lists('workingHours','timeKeeping_empID');
}
```

in your view

```
foreach ($timeLogData as $timeLogDatas) {
{{$timeLogDatas->user->name}} - {{$timeLogDatas->workingHours}}
}
```

In your **Time_Logs** model you have to use this function

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee','EmployeeID');
    }
```

EXtra : i guess you have to use this into your **Time_Logs**

```
protected $dates = [
        'log_in',
        'log_out',

    ];
```

Comment: I tried using your code but there is an error, it says "Trying to get property of a non-object". :(

Comment: @PatriciaArante first check in your controller function dd($timeLogData) will you get output ?let me know

Comment: @PatriciaArante hey i thought u geting employee name from User Table now check my answer ... check `user()` function in **Time_Logs** model

Comment: @PatriciaArante try to get a property :)